# What "Secure Payment" messaging has the best conversion rate?

Tags: payment, conversion-rate

Has anyone ever published what the security message has the highest conversion rate?

The standard one I see is "This is a secure 128-bit SSL encrypted payment"

But is there any data to support that this is the most effective sentence out there?

Comment: While I don't know any exact studies or sources, experience would lead me to believe that the iconography is almost more important than any text.

Answer (score 2):

One of the most widely used statements in the industry us "PCI Compliant". Most educated merchants look for this statement before even calling about a product or service.

Some other suggestions Ive pulled from some big name players in the industry;

- "We've been a trusted partner for payments since 1996."
  (authorize.net)
- End-to-end encrypting card reader, data tokenization, locked-down
  operating system, and mutually authenticated SSL are just a few of
  the technologies we've built into Clover. (clover.com)

For reference; www.pcisecuritystandards.org